# Upload file not save on local folder but in database display data Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I learn with laravel about last week, and now im stuck with upload file.
I have search and try another way but still not working.

**I have make coding like this**

```js
public function store(Request $request)
{  
  $article = new Article();  
  $article->title = Input::get('title');
  $article->description = Input::get('description');
  $article->author = Input::get('author'); 
  
  if($request->hasFile('image') ==  "")
  {
    $article->image = $request->image;
  } else
  {
    $file = Input::file('image');
    //upload path
    $destinationPath = 'img/gallery/';
    //getting timestamp
    $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    //setting name
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(). '-' .$timestamp;  
    $article->image = $filename; 
    //move to path              
    $file->move($destinationPath,  $filename);                
  }

  $article->save(); 

  // sending back with message 
  return redirect()->route('articles.index')->with('message', 'File Success added!');               
}
```

**For Model Code**

```js
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
 protected $fillable =
 [  
  'title', 
  'author', 
  'description', 
  'image'
 ];
}
```

**And this for view code**

```js
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('image', 'Choose an image') !!}
 {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '']) !!}
 <span id="image-error" class="help-block"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">     
 {!! Form::label("image","Preview Image") !!}
 <div class="image articles auth">
  @if(isset($articles))
   <img class="fit-cover" src="{{asset('img/gallery/'.$article->image.'')}}" id="showPicture" /> 
  @else
   <img class="fit-cover" src="http://placehold.it/625x1200" id="showPicture" /> 
  @endif         
 </div>
</div>
```

That code success for others input. But not for file image. 
In database image column is success display. But in local file image not store in folder. So the image can not display.

> http://localhost:8000/img/gallery/fashion-man-person-hand.jpg

Thank you master :)

**I upload image for error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCvZK.jpg)

Comment: Your problem is image preview not showing?

Comment: yes. not showing because file image not store in folder localhost img/gallery. i make this path $destinationPath = 'img/gallery/';